# customizable ListView

Tags: android, listview, user-interface

What is the best approach "playing" with the design of a `ListView` (and of course the `ListItem`).
I'm not looking for something really fancy, just giving the right background, changing the font family and size and put the text in the middle.

I followed a tutorial suggested creating an `Adapter` and implementing the method `getView`. It actually worked but I wonder if there's a simpler way for my terms.

Thanks.

Comment: Customizing the Adapter is the best and the simplest way, Else you have to extend the listview and write your own custom control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No this is the best way for doing listviews